# c++ how to display the string searching key word with its exact line number?

Tags: c++

I have a programmer for c++ that ask me a file name first, then ask for the search word. the line that contains it should be displayed with its exact line number in front.
for example:
  20:XXXXXX. 
I have code here. I don't know how to display the line number. please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> //to work with strings
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int occurenceNumber = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int lineNum;
    string fileName;
    string toSearch; 
    string lineRead;

    ifstream inputFile;

    cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;


    inputFile.open(fileName);

    if(!inputFile){
        cout << "Error opening file, or file doesn't exist!";
        cout << "Try again!\n";

        return 0;
    }


    cout << "Enter string to search for: ";
    cin >> toSearch;


    cin.ignore();

    while(getline(inputFile, lineRead))
    {


        if(lineRead.find(toSearch, 0) < lineRead.length())
        {
            occurenceNumber++;
            cout << lineRead << endl;

        }

    }


    cout << toSearch << " was found " << occurenceNumber;
    cout << " times. \n";


    inputFile.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set a counter variable. You just forgot to use it. This is the while loop in your code with that counter variable that you defined but forgot to use.

If you place the counter++ at the beginning of that while loop, the first line is line 1. On the other hand, if you place it at the end of the loop, the first line is line 0.

```
while(getline(inputFile, lineRead))
{
    counter++;
    if(lineRead.find(toSearch, 0) < lineRead.length())
    {
        occurenceNumber++;
        cout << counter << ":" << lineRead << endl;

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I know what you said. if I put counter++. when I search " him" . it will show as : 01: I remember him. ... but actually, this line should be  20  in file, not 01 or 00. i need it show its exact line in file.

Comment: that is your actual line in the file. Each time you read a line in the file, the value of that counter will increase by one. Thus, it is only the matter of taste between you want the first line in your file is line 0 or 1.